# Whats wrong with this inline style ternary

Tags: reactjs

I'm just getting an error here. I'm trying to give styling to a certain condition and not too sure why this isn't working. If the `unittestsmode === 'database'`, it should return the first line, else if it is an Object, it should return the second.

```
<div  {unitTestsMode === 'Database' ? style={width: '30%', marginRight: '10px'} : style={width: '20%'}  }>
  <DropdownSingle
    options={['Object', 'Database']}
    value='Object'
    name='Search unit tests'
    onChange={onChangeUnitTestsMode}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: this has to do with what happens when the component gets transformed from JSX to javascript. The easiest way to do this with a single attribute is to put the ternary statement in the attribute not around it i.e. `<div style={ condition ? { width: 20 }: { width: 10 }}>`

Comment: `style={unitTestsMode === 'Database' ? {width: '30%', marginRight: '10px'} : {width: '20%'}}`

Answer (score 2):

It should be conditional object for `style`

```
<div style={unitTestsMode === 'Database' ? {width: '30%', marginRight: '10px'} : {width: '20%'}}>
    <DropdownSingle
        options={['Object', 'Database']}
        value='Object'
        name='Search unit tests'
        onChange={onChangeUnitTestsMode}
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conditional rendering in a separate variable and based on the answer set the styling of the div.

```
const unitTestsMode = 'Database';

const style = unitTestsMode==='Database'? {width: '30%', marginRight: '10px'}: {width: '20%'}
 
  <div style={style}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're modifying one property of the `style` object, I would do something like this where you have a ternary operator for the `width` property. You can also bring the contents of the `style` prop out into a separate variable for organizational reasons.

```
<div style={{
   marginRight: '10px',
   width: unitTestsMode === 'Database' ? '30%' : '20%',
}}>
  <DropdownSingle
    options={['Object', 'Database']}
    name='Search unit tests'
    onChange={onChangeUnitTestsMode}
    value='Object'
  />
</div>
```